# how to return information about object without object id

Tags: ruby, database, class, oop

I am new to ruby. I have attribute accessors for id, title and author name. I want the object returned to return:

1 - Emma - Jane Austen

but I get :
#<Books:0x0000151181e18 @id ="1", @title="Emma",@author_name= "Jane Austin">

my code:

```
books_repository = BooksRepository.new
books_repository.all

books_repository = BooksRepository.new
books_repository.all.each do |book|
  p book
end
```

my class :

```
class BooksRepository
  def all
    query = "SELECT id, title, author_name FROM books;"
    params = []
    result_set = DatabaseConnection.exec_params(query, params)
    books = []
    result_set.each {|record| 
      book = Books.new
      book.id = record["id"]
      book.title = record["title"]
      book.author_name = record["author_name"]
      books << book
    }
    books
  end   
end
```

Comment: I don't see any object being returned in your code. Can you clarify your question, please?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the above question to include the class. I am currently using sql. I have a database called books which has the columns id, title and author name which I will be using in attribute accessors. I then created a Book repository class with the method all to get the record info and store in an array

Answer (score 2):

Implement a `inspect` method in your Books class which defines a representation of the object to your liking:

```
class Books
  def inspect
    "#{id} - #{title} - #{author_name}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Upvoted, but was shocked at the plural until I reread the question example